# How to track a stolen Canon EOS camera using SDHC memory card?

Tags: geo-tagging, memory-cards, digital-cameras

A few years back I've purchased an [Eye-Fi Pro X2](https://x2help.eyefi.com/) for my Canon EOS digital camera.

Unfortunately, the camera has been stolen and at that time I had my photo sync disabled in [*Eye-Fi Center*](https://center.eye.fi/) (which is now deprecated) and I couldn't do anything to activate it back remotely (either to re-activate sync of the photos or track the thief location based on the access point where the card is connected to). Now X2 is End of Life anyway.

I'd like to know what I can do in the future to deal with similar situations using the latest version of [Eye-Fi](http://www.eyefi.com/) SDHC memory cards.

In other words, I'd like to know whether it's possible to track the location of the lost camera remotely (assuming the camera is on with its card intact), or at least re-activating disabled photo sync remotely (assuming the card has been registered correctly). What should I activate or configure in order to prepare for the next potential incident?

Comment: The most low-tech option is to take a picture with your email address on it. That way you help people or the police track you down to return the photos on the card. And watch your camera more closely. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As detailed in my answer to the precision question (https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/341/78) the current generation of sdcards doesn't seem to support inherent geo-location capabilities anymore. Furthermore, [Eye-Fi was bought by Ricoh](http://www.digitaltrends.com/photography/ricoh-eyefi-acquisition-pentax-dslr/). Looking at their product portfolio they seem to prefer to include the GPS function in the camera right away or offer additional GPS modules.

Have a look at this [blog about geo-tagging photos](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/gps-trackers-geotagging-photos). SD cards aren't even listed there anymore and I couldn't find any decent and recent sdcards with inherent geo-tagging. The trend seems to be different. The new [Canon EOS 7D](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O2AHP1Q) has inbuilt GPS already.

How to get your camera back after it's been stolen is of course extremely model based and cannot be answered in general.