# Eye-Fi vs Transcend: Which card provides more accurate geotagging?

Tags: geo-tagging, memory-cards

There are two leading companies in the Wi-Fi memory card market.

I'd like to know how they compare in terms of accurate geotagging data of the taken photos, especially when travelling around in rural areas (away from cities) or in North African countries.

As far as I know, Eye-Fi cards must be within range of at least 2 Wi-Fi Access Points, and these devices must be 'known' by the Google WPS database. The geotagging happens during the upload process to the servers and it is not possible to redo this once photos have been uploaded.

Based on the above, how do [Transcend cards](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-401) compare to [Eye-Fi Mobi Pro](https://www.amazon.com/Eye-Fi/b/?node=2529407011) in terms of geolocation accuracy (assuming their technical specs of the latest models)? Are they equal?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the last generations of the SD cards don't offer geo-tagging themselves at all. (Cf. with geo-tagging completely missing on any product specs.) The usual way nowadays seems to be to have the card automatically connect to the smartphone and use the phones location services. Thus, your tagging will be exactly as precise as your phones location service.

This blogger for example reviews the new Eye-Fi SD card:

> One neat touch is that you can tell the Eyefi Mobi app to use your phone’s GPS to track your location while you’re out shooting, and then use this to geotag your images.

[Source Blog about Eye-Fi](http://www.amateurphotographer.co.uk/accessory_reviews/eyefi-mobi-pro-wi-fi-sdhc-card-review-69490#lcmq4qtHfAiVrX58.99)

The accuracy of civilian GPS without Wi-Fi location support, as it will be likely in rural areas, is described for example [here on the information site of the US government.](http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/)